# MySQL queries on phpmyadmin works on localhost but fails in remote server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some queries that work 100% when I run on my localhost, but they give me syntax error when I try to run then remotely.

Here is one of the queries:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` text,
  `date_modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` text,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_credit` text,
  `registration_ip_address` text,
  `last_name` text,
  `tax_exempt_category` text,
  `date_created` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` text,
  `notes` text,
  `company` text,
  `customer_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Here is the error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL, `first_name` text, `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,' at line 4
```

The weird thing is that it's the exact same query! I tried to run remotely on two different hosting services I have, and they both give me the same syntax error.

I have no clue how to solve it. Anyone has any idea what might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Mysql version is lower. Can you execute and see.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` text,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` text,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_credit` text,
  `registration_ip_address` text,
  `last_name` text,
  `tax_exempt_category` text,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` text,
  `notes` text,
  `company` text,
  `customer_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It worked! Is there any other change you made besides removing the parenthesis and the numbe after datetime? And is there a way to export from phpmyadmin a database for a lower version?

Comment: Sorry that questions i don't have any answers. Thank you please accept my answer.

Comment: In 5 minutes, I just accepted another and have to wait a bit =)